# Удаление каждого k-го элемента в списке

Tags: c++

в процессе написания кода возникла проблема. Вот условие задачи:"Считалочка. N ребят расположены по кругу. Каждому присвоен номер по порядку. Начав отсчёт от
первого, удаляют каждого k-ого, смыкая при этом круг. Определить номер последнего, оставшегося
в круге. (k<=N)"

```
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* Next;
};

class List
{
    Node* Head;

public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void push_back(int x);//добавление элементов
    void Show();//отображение списка на экране
    void pop_front();//удаление первого элемента
    void clear();//удаление списка

    void removeAt(List* lst, int k);//удаление нужных элементов;
    void LastElement();//поиск последнего элемента

    int GetSize(){ return Size; }
    int Size;//число элементов в списке

};

List::List()
{
    Size = 0;
    Head = NULL;
}

List::~List()
{
    clear();
}

void List::push_back(int x)//добавление элементов 
{
    Node* newlink = new Node;//выделение памяти
    newlink->data = x;//запоминаю данные
    newlink->Next = Head;//запоминаю значение Head
    Head = newlink;//Head теперь указывает на новый элемент
}

void List::Show()//вывод на экран списка
{
    Node* current = Head; //начиная с первого элемента
    while (current)//пока есть данные
    {
        cout << current->data << " ";
        current = current->Next;
    }
}

void List::pop_front()//удаление первого элемента
{
    //Node* temp = new Node;//выделение памяти

    Node* temp = Head;
    Head = Head->Next;//теперь список начинается со следующего элемента
    delete temp;//удаление первого элемента

    Size--;
}

void List::clear()//удаление всего списка
{
    while (Size)
    {
        pop_front();
    }
}

void List::removeAt(List* lst, int k)
{
    Node* current = lst->Head;//текущий элемент списка

    while (current != nullptr)//прохожу по списку
    {
        if (current->data % k == 0)
        {
            Node* tmp = current->Next;
            current->Next = tmp->Next;

            delete tmp;
        }
        current = current->Next;
    }
}

void List::LastElement()
{
    

}
////////////////////
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    List lst;//переменная-список
    Node* Head = new Node;
    int N, k, x;
    cout << "Введите количество ребят N: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x = i;
        lst.push_back(x);
    }

    lst.Show();

    cout << "Введите k: " << endl;
    cin >> k;

    lst.removeAt(Head, k);

    cout << "Список после обработки: " << endl;
    lst.Show();

    cout << "Последний элемент обработанного списка: " << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять, как определить номер последнего, оставшегося в круге. Также проблема возникла здесь
`lst.removeatAt(Head,k);`
Не знаю, что передать вместо Head.

Comment: Можно замкнуть список в кольцо и бегать по нему циклами по k - 1 перемещений к следующему. Удалить следующий элемент. Проверить, если текущий ссылается сам на себя, то он последний оставшийся. Иначе повторить цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все намного проще. Многократно разобранная *задача Иосифа*.

```
int J(int n, int k)
{
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return (J(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1;
}

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << J(n,k) << endl;
}
```

Или итеративно:

```
int J(int n, int k)
{
    int j = 1;
    for(int m = 1; m < n; ++m)
    {
        j = (j+k-1)%(m+1)+1;
    }
    return j;
}
```